# Concolic Testing of c programs

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I have been given a project to create a concolic testing framework for testing c programs. i found that CUTE and DART implement concolic testing. But they are not available for download. I completely understand the way concolic testing works but I am not able to implement it at system level. Can someone help? I need help regarding on how to extract components/functions of a c program, test them concretely and symbolically and hit possible errors in the program.

Comment: what is concolic testing?

Comment: Hm this is quite dated, but... Did you ever make progress? A concolic testing framework is not something you can easily implement in  four weeks by one person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CREST](https://code.google.com/p/crest/) is an open-source implementation of concolic testing.

Answer (score 1):

[CATG](https://github.com/ksen007/janala2) and [Jalangi](https://github.com/SRA-SiliconValley/jalangi) are open-source implementations of concolic testing for Java and JavaScript programs, respectively.